# Create unset cookie button

Tags: php, cookies, button, session-cookies, unset

I have created a cookie using php and now I need to create a button the user can click to log out.

This would be the php code to unset the cookie:

```
 unset($_COOKIE['access_token']);
```

But I'm a quite stuck with how to make the button functionality. Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unseting $_COOKIE won't actually delete the cookie. You can however overwrite it with an expiration date set in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {`

`unset($_COOKIE['access_token']);`

`header('Location: /');`

`exit;`

`}`

on site

`<a href="?logout">logout</a>`

Comment: As others have said, this actually doesn't delete the cookie. `setcookie('access_token', null, 0, '/');` does.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you can delete cookie by setting time in past

```
setcookie($_COOKIE['access_token'],'',time()-3600);
```

you should unset session

```
session_destroy()'
```

Comment: Thanks to all and sorry I tried to make it simple and I made it too simple. I have a session in my web in which the user is logged in, and there's the login to Foursquare. What I'm trying to do is to build a button to log out from Foursquare but not from my session..and you're right unsetting the cookie is not working :(

Comment: @user638009: If there is session you must use `session_unset` for that site (Foursquare)and `session_destroy`. Session and cookie both are different

Comment: ok, but how I make the difference in between my session and Foursquare session? there's nothing called session.. in the Foursquare auth code.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually best to do:

```
setcookie("myCookie", null, 1); //# This will expire / delete *immediately*
```

If you use

```
setcookie("myCookie", null, 0), the cookie is still valid until they close their browser.
```